# Hide SharePoint List Item based on Condition using Views

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I have list holding customer name and expiry date list items .And I need to create a view which should hide all the customers whose expiration date is passed

Example : If Customer A is holding expiry date at 2015-(05) MAY 25 then this view should not display customer A in the list

Can any one help me how can I done this using views

Answer (score 1):

You can create a filter for that.

- Go to view settings
- Scroll down to filter section
- Select Radio Button "Show Items only when following is true"
- Under "Show the item when column" dropdown, select field of expiry date
- Under comparison operators dropdown, select "is less than"
- In third dropdown, enter `[Today]`
- Save the view and verify results

Comment: HI,Thanks for your support ,But when I follow your steps I don't find any items in the list.Can you please look further in helping me

Comment: What is the field type of expiry date? is it dte/time?if yes, what is the format? Also, what is the regional setting for date/time on server and on the machine from which you are accessing URL?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this right you have one list. In that case under create view/ modify view go to filters and select the rules. If it doesn't pass the filters then it hides the item.

If you have two lists and you have to hide item in listA based on listB then you should be able to do it by workflow which is activated by a retention job (Settings-information management) on list B once due date has passed.